# how to perform inverse pyramid for given interger array list values? in android

Tags: java, arrays, list

```
 4  5  7  6 3
  9  3  4  9
   3  7  4
    1   2
      3
```

4+5=9

5+7=12 -->1+2=3

Likewise, how to get final result 3 like `n` number?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    int rows = 5;

    for(int i = rows; i >= 1; --i) {
        for(int space = 1; space <= rows - i; ++space) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }

        for(int j=i; j <= 2 * i - 1; ++j) {
           System.out.print("* ");
            //System.out.print(a[j]);
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < i - 1; ++j) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code, provided that the numbers are in an array, as I cannot find a pattern in the numbers you have provided.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numList[] = {4, 5, 7, 6, 3, 9, 3, 4, 9, 3, 7, 4, 1, 2, 3};
        int i,j=0,k=1; //k is for the spaces.

        for (int line = 4; line >= 0; line--) {

            // To display spaces
                for(int space=0; space<k; space++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");

                }
             // To display the numbers.
                for (i = j; i <= (j + line); i++) {
            // The below if statement is for symmetry, you may ignore it.
                    if(k>=1){
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                    System.out.print(" "+numList[i]+" ");
                }
                j = i;
                //The below code is just to make the pyramid symmetrical you
                //may ignore it.
                if(k==0){
                    k++;
                }
                else{
                    k+=2;
                }

                System.out.println();
            }
       }
```

Output

[image]

Comment: hi apputhanks, i may not explained in well manner. the first row each values added to one another and result form second row,likewise other rows finally got single digit.

Comment: 4+5=9, 5+7=12 --->1+2=3,7+6=13----1+3=4 likewise sum of numbers bigger than 9 means again add that number one more time.

Comment: I see, in that case you can just take the first row and create another array to store the totals and assign them to the below rows respectively.